# Effective way to group by OR condition

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a large list of header/position items. I try to group the positions by properties of the header.

The headers are grouping conditions so I order the headers to get the positions for specific interests. The specific interests are concated by OR conditions.
To extract the the positions by interests, I iterate over the list of headers.
I'm searching a better way to order the positions by the specific interests than to iterate over the whloe list of headers.

In the example is only one specific interest described, which calls ExampleFunction().

```
    class Header
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }
        public int C { get; set; }
        public int D { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Position> Positions { get; set; }
        public Header(int a, int b, int c, int d) { A = a; B = b; C = c; D = d; }
    }
    class Position
    {
        public int P1 { get; set; }
        public int P2 { get; set; }
        public Position(int p1, int p2) { P1 = p1; P2 = p2; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var itemList = new List<Header>()
            {
                new Header(1,1,1,0) {Positions = new List<Position>() {new Position(3,5) } },
                new Header(1,1,1,1) {Positions = new List<Position>() {new Position(1,2) } },
                new Header(1,2,2,0) {Positions = new List<Position>() {new Position(8,7) } },
                new Header(1,2,3,0) {Positions = new List<Position>() {new Position(0,1) } },
                new Header(2,2,2,2) {Positions = new List<Position>() {new Position(1,0) } },
                new Header(3,2,2,1) {Positions = new List<Position>() {new Position(10,5) } },
                new Header(1,0,0,0) {Positions = new List<Position>() {new Position(11,5) } },
                new Header(1,0,2,0) {Positions = new List<Position>() {new Position(3,5) } },
            };

            var orderedItemList = itemList.OrderBy(i => i.A)
                                          .ThenBy(i => i.B)
                                          .ToList();
            Header oldItem = null;
            var positions = new List<Position>();
            foreach(var item in orderedItemList)
            {
                if (oldItem == null)
                {
                    oldItem = item;
                    continue;
                }
                else if (item.A != oldItem.A || item.B != oldItem.B)
                {
                    ExampleFunction(positions);
                    positions.Clear();
                }
                oldItem = item;
                positions.AddRange(item.Positions);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void ExampleFunction(IEnumerable<Position> positions)
        {
            // Do something with the positions
        }
    }
```

Comment: You described solution for some problem. What is the problem?

Comment: The Problem is, that it is not performant to iterate over a list of some thousand items. So I'm looking for an improvement for this solution.

Comment: Why do need to iterate? What do you want to find?

Comment: I iterate the list, because I need to know when a special property changes. In fact, the event creates a new list with all items, which where past before the event occurred. The example code is a simpler way to demonstrate the problem. In fact there are many more properties and special properties in my real list.

Comment: From current state it looks like you are looking for something 'reactive', but it is not clear what to suggest since there is no specific problem described.

Comment: OK, so you want to detect differences between a row an the next row. Yeah, that requires iterating over the whole list. But the iteration itself shouldn't be a problem, that's millisecond level. The problem is the complex pair-wise comparison. You should show a more realistic example to help us diagnose where the shoe pinches.

Comment: @Gert: You are right, I want detect differences between two rows. But I sorted the list by the special properties, before I iterate it. So I have grouped the list and the event only occures in a group change. Would the condition for the event are concated by an AND, I don't have to iterate over the whole list, to detect the group changes. I can group by the specific properties. But here is an OR condition. I hoped there is a same performant way to detect the group changes for an OR-Condition, like the GROUP-Methode in the AND-Condition.

Comment: If these records don't have any specific order it's absolutely unclear to me what you're trying to achieve. If you order them before detecting transitions you can create/hide any transition at will.

Comment: They will be ordered by             var orderedItemList = itemList.OrderBy(i => i.A)
                                          .ThenBy(i => i.B)
                                          .ToList();

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear, what you want to do. But I have some ideas.

You can use [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) type. It has event [CollectionChanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8). It can help you to detect if item was added, removed, or list was reset.

Also, you can implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) interface on your class and decet propery changed in Item.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. But the values of the list will not change. It's more a grouping of values with different triggers which are concated by an OR-Operation.

Comment: i am not clear, what do you need as result: list of properties with old/new values for properties which value changed?